# INSERT INTO using Postgres on PYTHON DB-API

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, python-db-api

I'm trying to learn to add backend to a simple web app using postgreSQL and Python DB-API.

When running the app, why do I get an error if the function **get_posts()** in forumdb. python uses `c. execute ("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time;)` instead of `SELECT content, time FROM posts ORDER BY time;)`?

Secondly, can anyone explain why `c.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES (content)")` doesn't work and we have to use the `('%s') % content` thing in the function **add_post(content)** in forumdb.py?

Below is forum.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for

# Using a module called forumdb
from forumdb import get_posts, add_post

app = Flask(__name__)

# HTML template for the forum page
HTML_WRAP = '''\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DB Forum</title>
    <style>
      h1, form { text-align: center; }
      textarea { width: 400px; height: 100px; }
      div.post { border: 1px solid #999;
                 padding: 10px 10px;
                 margin: 10px 20%%; }
      hr.postbound { width: 50%%; }
      em.date { color: #999 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>DB Forum</h1>
    <form method=post>
      <div><textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea></div>
      <div><button id="go" type="submit">Post message</button></div>
    </form>
    <!-- post content will go here -->
%s
  </body>
</html>
'''

# HTML template for an individual comment
POST = '''\
    <div class=post><em class=date>%s</em><br>%s</div>
'''


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
  '''Main page of the forum.'''
  posts = "".join(POST % (date, text) for text, date in get_posts())
  html = HTML_WRAP % posts
  return html


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def post():
  '''New post submission.'''
  message = request.form['content']
  add_post(message)
  return redirect(url_for('main'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Below is forumdb.py

```
# "Database code" for the DB Forum.

import psycopg2
import datetime


def get_posts():
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="forum")
    c = con.cursor()
    """Return all posts from the 'database', most recent first."""
    c.execute("SELECT content, time FROM posts ORDER BY time;")
    return c.fetchall()
    con.close()


def add_post(content):
    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="forum")
    c = con.cursor()
    """Add a post to the 'database' with the current timestamp."""
    c.execute("INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('%s')" % content)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: `VALUS` should be `VALUES` in the insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using  parameterized query is a query in which placeholders are used for parameters and the parameter values are supplied at execution time.

When we want to use a variable inside a SQL query you need to use a placeholder for it.

Example

```
query = """Update table set column_a = %s where column_b = %s"""
```